# Is it possible to build a Java 11 HttpClient that uses SSL/TLS JAVA_OPTS as its SSLContext?

Tags: java, ssl, java-11, java-http-client

I know with Apache's `HttpClientBuilder` you can call `useSystemProperties()` and it will create a client with an `SSLContext` configured from the `javax.net.ssl.keyStore` (and truststore) if passed as `JAVA_OPTS`:

```
try (CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().useSystemProperties.build()) {
  // If javax.net.ssl props are set, make requests that require client auth
  // Otherwise make regular requests
}
```

I want to do something similar with the Java 11 `HttpClient`.  The reason for this is in my use-case, I am treating key stores and trust stores as optional and it would be nice to not have to check their existence in my code.  Basically, I want to set an `SSLContext` based on `JAVA_OPTS` if they exist; otherwise just use the [`"Default"` context](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpClient.Builder.html#sslContext(javax.net.ssl.SSLContext)).

Comment: That's what already happens by default.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TLDR: you don't need to do anything

New `java.net.http.HttpClient`, like older `HttpsURLConnection` and also plain `SSL[Server]Socket` and other things, defaults to `SSLContext.getDefault()` which **by default uses the system properties** `javax.net.ssl.{key,trust}Store*` -- reading them only once, the first time it is referenced in a given JVM; any settings made after that (necessarily by code) are ignored.

The initial values of these system properties (like others input to the JVM, rather than automatically set like `java.version`) can be set by the `-D` option on the command line *or* in the `_JAVA_OPTIONS` environment variable; both of these can also be used to set other system properties that have nothing to do with SSL/TLS and other options that are not system properties. Java itself does not use env var `JAVA_OPTS`, but some things that *run* Java as a subordinate (like service monitors, IDEs, toolchains, etc, etc) may use (the contents of) that env var as part of the created command line.

Note if you *don't* specify the sysprops, the truststore defaults to JRE/lib/security/cacerts (which is normally supplied with 'standard' public CAs like Verisign/Symantec/Digicert, GoDaddy, etc) but the keystore has no default, i.e. no client authentication is done.

Comment: Yep!  And that's what I thought too.  My problem was actually that `JAVA_OPTS` needed to be changed to `_JAVA_OPTIONS` and my app picked it right up.